# Complex GUI in clojure

Tags: swing, clojure

I just started using clojure today (however , I have used Java a lot and know of functional paradigms) and I was wondering if it was a good idea to build a clojure app with a reasonable complex interface (dragging, dropping, panning, zooming,...) using Swing?

I can imagine that a lot of the normal swing logics (especially concerning OO) has to be bypassed one way or the other..

I asume that all is possible , but is it possible in a way that justifyable?

I mean wouldn't it be like hitting a nail with a screwdriver in stead of with a hammer?

Has anyone here have experience in building GUI's with Clojure (and of Course : is Swing the ideal candidate for that?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found it relatively easy to use Swing to build decent user interfaces in Clojure. You have a couple of options about how to do it however:

- Write the code pretty much as you would in Java, just using the Java interop from Clojure to call the relevant Swing APIs. [This article](http://stuartsierra.com/2010/01/03/doto-swing-with-clojure) does a good job of explaining how, with a bit of macro magic as well to make your life easier.
- Use a Clojure GUI wrapper for Swing, e.g. [seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) or [clj-swing](https://github.com/Licenser/clj-swing). My take is that these tools have the potential to help you write some really neat GUI code in idiomatic Clojure

Comment: Thanks, I see that it can be done, however can added complexity (that I could handel in Java/swing) be a nogo later on in building the app?  Isn't there stuff that can be overlooked?  In Swing I used to build my own MVC (where datachange triggered the GUI) : I guess that still is possible?  Again the given example is nice and usefull, but still very trivial...

Comment: There really isn't anything in Swing/Java that you can't do in Clojure - ultimately it's possible to call any Swing/Java function through the Java interop if you need to. Of course you need to manage the complexity as your application grows, but I'd argue that this is actually easier in Clojure than Java/Swing (because of higher order functions, minimal boilerplate, macros etc.)

Comment: You may also want to look at a library that I wrote to facilitate GUI programming: https://github.com/jonasseglare/signe. It lets you wrap the state of your program represented as an immutable data structure inside a single atom. I provide three examples to illustrate how it works.

Answer (score 6):

One really cool feature of Clojure's [software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) subsystem is that it allows you to set watches on variables: whenever the variable is changed (by anything), your callback gets executed. This lends itself to a powerful sort of GUI programming where the GUI updates itself automagically based on the state of your variables.

A short but non-trivial Swing GUI example is described in detail at http://www.paullegato.com/blog/swing-clojure-gui-black-scholes/ .

Answer (score 1):

Since others are mentioning swing related answers, I'll ask you one question: Is Swing a requirement. Although writing Swing code in clojure is more pleasant then in Java, it is still Swing, with all its verbosity and annoyances, especially in complex application with hard set requirements.

Have you considered web UI, where Clojure fits much more natural? Or **SWT** or **QT Jambi**, which also can be made to work using Clojure.

Comment: +1 : No swing is no requirement, that's why I state : (and of Course : is Swing the ideal candidate for that?) Of course I have had some experience with Swing, I consider that a plus.